# SQL Server column max based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset as shown below in a booking table

```
Custid ApptDate     oldornewApp 
-------------------------------
  100    01-jan-2013  old
  100    01-jan-2014  old
  100    01-oct-2016  new
  100    12-oct-2016  new
  200    01-feb-2015  old
  200    10-oct-2016  new
```

I am trying for an output which shows max date based on the `oldornewapp` column for each customer

```
 custid  MaxApptDateOldApp  MaxapptDatenewapp
 ---------------------------------------------
 100     01-jan-2014        12-oct-2016
 200     01-feb-2015        10-oct-2016
```

Please let me know a best way to get the resultset, I am using SQL Server 2012

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Custid
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN oldornewApp = 'old' THEN ApptDate END) as MaxApptDateOldApp
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN oldornewApp = 'new' THEN ApptDate END) as MaxApptDateNewApp
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    Custid
```

You can use conditional aggregation to get to your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join  and group by

```
select old.Custid, max(old.ApptDate) as MaxApptDateOldApp, max(new.ApptDate) as MaxApptDateNewApp
from my_table as old
where a.oldornewApp = 'old';
group by a,Custid
inner join  (
    select b.Custid, max(b.ApptDate) as AppDate
    from my_table as b
    where b.oldornewApp = 'new';
    group by b.Custid
) new
```

Comment: this wont work if a custid doesn't have an OLD record but has a new record.  To use this type of join you would have to have a Cartesian join of custid to old and new and then LEFT JOIN both the old sub set and new sub set.